# Macro for copying random cells and pasting+transponing to random cells

Tags: vba, range

I've searched everywhere and just can't get it running. I'm fairly new(b) to VBA, so if it's possible i would be very happy with some tips or help.

So my recorded macro is this:

```
Range("C133:C134").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("AVGs").Select
Range("C28").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
```

My goal is to select and copy random cells and the pastespecial them in random cells on different worksheets.

I got this far:

```
Selection.Copy
Sheets("AVGs").Select


Set x = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Click in the column to copy to", Type:=8)
Range("x").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, Transpose:=True
```

But i just get and error and debugger shows error in `Range("x").Select` .....

Comment: `Each Range object is defined by a starting and ending character position` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223066(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: If you've verified that x is in fact a range, you don't need the quotes around it in `Range("x")`

Comment: I tried it also without quotes with the same result.

Comment: what do you mean by saying **`random`**?

Comment: by random I mean not preselected cells (as in the first code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page on InputBoxes ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195768(v=office.11).aspx

Type 8 indicates that the inputbox should return a range object

`8  A cell reference, as a Range object`

If this is the case, then you only need to do

`x.Select`

In order to select the range indicated by the user.  If you used type = 2, then you would use `Range(x).Select`

After that, the last line in your macro is the same as the one in the procedure, so you should be off and running

Edit, new Code:

```
Set x = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Set cell to copy", Type:=8) 
x.Select 
Selection.Copy 
Sheets("AVGs").Select 
Set y = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Set cell to paste", Type:=8) 
y.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it worked on the Range(x).select or now x.select line but now it returns a new error in the last line.

Comment: last code is this:

Set x = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Set cell to copy", Type:=8)
    
x.Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("AVGs").Select


Set y = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Set cell to paste", Type:=8)
y.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub

Sadly it just doesn't want to run, it calls error in the last line

Comment: Easiest way to debug this is to remove the additional arguments, and add them back one at a time